# React image not showing while passing src attribute through props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am trying to display an image from public/images folder. Trying to pass image src to props. All other values like label and text I can access with props. But {props.src} and {props.path} not providing expected result. Instead its being displayed as it is as shown in the screenshot. Please advice

Cards.js

```
import React from 'react';
import CardItem from './CardItem';
import './Cards.css';


function Cards() {
  return (
    <div className='cards'>
        <h1>Check out these epic destinations!</h1>
        <div className='cards__container'>
            <div className='cards__wrapper'>
                <ul className='cards__items'>
                    <CardItem
                        src= 'images/img-9.jpg'
                        text='Explore the hidden waterfall deep inside the amazon jungle'
                        label='adventure'
                        path='/services'
                    />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cards
```

CardItem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function CardItem(props) {
  return (
    <>
        <li className="cards__item">
            <Link to="{props.path}" className="cards__item__link">
                <figure className='cards_item_pic-wrap' data-category={props.label}>
                    <img src={'props.src'} alt="Meditation image" className='cards__item__img' />
                </figure>
                <div className='cards__item__info'>
                    <h5 className='cards__item__text'>{props.text}</h5>
                </div>
            </Link>
        </li>
    </>
  )
}

export default CardItem
```

Screenshot
[image]

Comment: It should be `<img src={props.src}` not `<img src={'props.src'}` inside `CardItem`.

Comment: It's just a silly mistake, change `src={'props.src'}` to `src={props.src}`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `src={'props.src'}` to `src={props.src}`

Answer (score 0):

Very often problem to me also. I use require() to invoke the image:

```
                <CardItem
                 src= ${require("image_path")}                            
                 text='Explore the hidden waterfall deep inside the amazon jungle'
                 label='adventure'
                    />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<img alt="Meditation image" src={props.src} />
```